# Manually pre-flighting a CORS request is failing due to CORS issues

Tags: cors, fetch, preflight

I'm trying to manually send an OPTIONS requests to check in advance if CORS is going to be a problem (so I can tell users on startup CORS is going to be an issue they need to fix, rather than wait until they have to PUT something and hit an error then).

I can't just PUT some random data on the service up front to test if it fails due to CORS, so I'm trying to send an OPTIONS request explicitly similar to the below:

```js
  const putResponse = await fetch(someUri, {
    method: "OPTIONS",
    headers: [
      ["Access-Control-Request-Method", "PUT"],
      [
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
        "x-ms-date,x-ms-version,x-ms-blob-type",
      ],
    ],
  });
  if (!putResponse.ok) throw Error("CORS preflight request failed");
```

However, it looks in the network tab like the browser is pre-flighting my OPTIONS request! (i.e. sending an OPTIONS request with "Access-Control-Request-Method: OPTIONS"). As the resource is configured to allow only GET and PUT, the manual pre-flight request itself is failing due to CORS errors, even though what it's checking for should work.

Is it possible to manually pre-flight a requests in advance without trying the actual request? If so, what is the best approach?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Besides, how could your users fix it if it turned out to be a problem? CORS settings are controlled by the server, which your users cannot change, I assume.